# How to deal with JSON error "rest_post_invalid_page_number"?

Tags: json, wordpress, reactjs

I am creating a React app that pulls in all content from a Wordpress site using API requests. Right now my problem is with the archive pages, i.e. pages of posts filtered by tag or category that can be loaded infinitely via a 'Load More' button. Here's how my GET request looks:

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tag=birds

And here's how it looks for pages different than the first one, once I click on 'Load More':

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tag=birds&page=2

This works fine except in one case. Suppose I've set the number of results to be shown on each page to be 8: if there are exactly 8 posts with the `birds` tag, then clicking on 'Load More' throws the following error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_post_invalid_page_number",
    "message": "The page number requested is larger than the number of pages available.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

The error makes sense, but I would prefer if no error was thrown and the request returned an empty array instead, because it would be easier for me to re-render the list base on a received empty array than a JSON error.

Can anyone suggest a solution to get what I want to achieve, or something similar to it?

Comment: If you don't want to receive an error instead an empty array then don't throw an error and return an empty array. what is blocking you from doing that ?

Comment: @ArjitaMitra I'm using Wordpress' default API. I have no control over when it should throw an error or not.

Comment: Then you have to manipulate the response. you can check the response code i.e rest_post_invalid_page_number and return an empty array. does that help ?

Comment: @ArjitaMitra Checking the response code is exactly what I'd like to avoid as it feels too weird... What I'm trying to ask here is if there's a way to modify Wordpress API's default behavior so that it returns an empty array instead of that JSON error when the number of results is exactly the same as the number of posts per page. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough!